# Determine all differentiable functions of the form $y = f(x)$ which have the properties $f ' (x) = (f (x))^3$ and $f (0) = 2$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, functions, derivatives

**Question :** Determine all differentiable functions of the form $y = f(x)$ which have the properties $f ' (x) = (f (x))^3$ and $f (0) = 2$

**My Try**
I have tried integrating the equation and what I got was

$f (x) = \frac{(f (x))^4}{4} + c$

Can someone give me a heads up so I know what direction to go?

Comment: Have you ever dealt with differential equations?

Comment: Yes, I'm not the best but I can generally work it out.

Answer (score 2):

You face $$\frac{dy}{dx}=y^3\implies \frac{dy}{y^3}=dx$$ Now integrate both sides $$\int\frac{dy}{y^3}=\int dx=x+C$$ I am sure that you can take it from here.

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is wrong because in L.H.S you integrated w.r.t. $x$ and in R.H.S you integrated  w.r.t. $y$.It would have been true if it was given that :

$$y' dx= y^3 dy \implies y = \frac{y^4}{4} + c$$

But it's not the case here , so Let $f(x)=y$

Given : 
$$~~~~~~~~\frac{dy}{dx}=y^3$$
$$ \implies \frac{dy}{y^3}=dx$$

Now integrate both the sides.

$$\int \frac{dy}{y^3}= \int dx$$

$$-\frac{1}{2y^2}=x+c$$

$$\Bigg( \text{Since}~\int y^n. dy= \frac{y^{n+1}}{n+1} \implies \int y^{-3}. dy= \frac{y^{-3+1}}{-3+1}=\frac{-1}{2y^2}\Bigg )$$

$$f(0)=2 \implies c=-\frac{1}{8}$$

Comment: Could you please show me the steps of how you got from integrating dy/y^3 to -1/2y^2? Cheers.

Comment: @PoChenLiu See my updated answer.